# Can I use benefits of as3 Workers to load external swfs

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, flash

I have Flash Builder application that loads heavy child swfs. UI freeze for few seconds when swf loaded. Swfs are of two types:

1. Swf with classes (similar to flex modules) - VM takes some time to parse bytes and add classes to application domain. Total swf size is about 2 MB.
2. Swf with shapes (converted pdf) - VM also parses classes and library content with UI lock. Swf size could be 0.5 - 10 MB.

So I wish to use as3 Workers (multi threading feature), but haven't seen similar example so far. Questions:

1. Does primary thread and children share the same Application domain (same classes)?
2. Can I pass display objects between workers? I guess no, as arguments should be serialized.

Stan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worker threads are virtual instances of Flash runtime so they don't share application domain.
You can only communicate between threads with MessageChannel (using `amf` serialized objects) and shared ByteArrays.

It's possible to serialize display objects with draw API to `ByteArray` or `amf` but I don't think this would be very efficient. This would be more realistic if you want to share bitmaps from workers.